# Is there any way to run a cruisecontrol project in some specific days at an specific time?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol

i know you can configure a project to be run at any time of the day, but is there the possibility to configure it to run only some specific days at any specific time?

Thanks in advance

--Victor

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer myself.

The cardinality of the child elements of the schedule ant task of the cruisecontrol config.xml file is 0..*. So you can add there as many entries as you want setting the day, like this:

```
<schedule>
  <antorwhatever day="Monday" time="0500" />
  <antorwhatever day="Wednesday" time="0700" />
</schedule>
```